# Show Webapi objects in view page by asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to separate each variable from the web service separately into the view page 
 there is a sample json string like my url resul

```
{"change":[{"object1": "value1", "object2": "value2", "object3": value3, "object4": value4},{"object1": "value1", "object2": "value2", "object3": value3, "object4": value4}]}

 public ActionResult Get_test(){WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
string url = "My URL";
webclient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));
webclient.Headers.Add("Request-type", "My Method");
string result = webclient.DownloadString(url);
```

}

how can i show the objects in a view.i have an empty view(Get_Test).

Comment: What "variables"?  What "view"?  It's not really clear what you're asking.  Please elaborate.

Comment: i edit my question.thank you lots..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public ActionResult Get_test(){
  WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
  webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = 
   "application/json;charset=utf-8";
  string url = "My URL";
  webclient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
  Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));
  webclient.Headers.Add("Request-type", "My Method");
  string result = webclient.DownloadString(url);`
 List<SampleViewModel> 
  userList = new List<SampleViewModel>();
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(result);
        JToken jUser = jObject["MyMethod"];
        foreach (var item in jUser)
        {
            SampleViewModel user = new SampleViewModel();
            user.object1 = (string)item["object1"];
            user.object2 = (string)item["object2"];
            user.object3 = (int)item["object3"];
            user.object4 = (int)item["object4"];
            userList.Add(user);
        }
    return view(userlist);
  }
```

at first i build a SampleViewModel with mt Objects.and then we have a foreach in view page

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.SampleViewModel>   
@{ViewBag.Title = "Get_Test";}
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>object1</th>
        <th>pobject2</th>
        <th>object3</th>
        <th>object4</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>@item.object1</td>
        <td>@item.object2</td>
        <td>@item.object3</td>
        <td>@item.pobject4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody> 
}
```